# Python 3: Finding word which appears the most times without using import or counter or dictionary, only simple tools like .split() and .lower()

Tags: python

I am currently learning Python and trying to solve a free tutorial question.

Here is the question.

A writer is working on their newest poem, Turing and the Machines. They have hired you to determine the word which appears the most times. You can access the lines of the poem by calling input() repeatedly, and the last line contains the three characters ###. All lines consist of words separated by single spaces; there are no digits or punctuation. Convert all the words to lower-case, and print the word that occurs the most times (we guarantee there will not be a tie). 
For example, if the input is

Here is a line like sparkling wine

Line up fast or be the last

# # #

Then the output should be

line

since it appears twice and no other word appears twice.

..........Below is the closest thing to a solution I can get.

It still lacks , among other things,  the facility to allow a user to call input() repeatedly.

And it only prints out the maximum number of the most used word , not the word itself that the question wants.

The poem is supplied by the website shell , at 
http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/15b-python-pushups/

Let's assume the user will input the poem one line at a time.

Please help. Thanks a million.

..........

```
def poem(P):

      P_lower = P.lower()

      P_split = P_lower.split()

      word_list = []

      wordfreq = []

      for i in P_split:
            word_list.append(i)

      for i in P_split:
            wordfreq.append(P_split.count(i))

      print(max(wordfreq))


poem('Here is a line like line sparkling line wine')
```

Comment: Is the poem in a file?

Comment: The poem is supplied by the website shell , at http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/15b-python-pushups/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't use any of the "restricted" tools but only lower(), split() and sort() to return the word with the most occurrences.

```
def  main():
    done = False
    P = ""
    while not done:
        new_line = input()
        if new_line != "###":
            P += new_line + " "
        else:
            done = True
    poem_words = P.lower().split()
    poem_words.sort()

    # Initialize variables
    temp = ""
    max_count = 0
    icount = 1
    max_word = ""

    # Do the loop
    for i in range(len(poem_words)):
        if temp == poem_words[i]:
            icount += 1
        else:
            temp = poem_words[i]
            icount = 1
        if icount > max_count:
            max_count = icount
            max_word = temp
    print(max_word)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: koukouviou , thank you very much for your efforts.
It looks way better than what I can come up with.
But unfortunately it fails the shell  in   Coding Exercise: Poetic Analysis     at 
http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/15b-python-pushups/
May be because we haven't learned lambda yet at that website.

Nor can I  get it to work in a Python 3 shell.
I would give you a vote up if I could . Thanks a million for your efforts once again.

Comment: koukouviou , thank you very much for your efforts.
It looks way better than what I can come up with.
But unfortunately it fails the shell  in   Coding Exercise: Poetic Analysis     at 
http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/15b-python-pushups/
May be because we haven't learned lambda yet at that website.

Nor can I  get it to work in a Python 3 shell.
I would give you a vote up if I could . Thanks a million for your efforts once again.

Comment: I edited the response to correct that. Feel free to accept the answer if it works

Comment: But it still fail the shell at  http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/15b-python-pushups/

I wounder if you could bother to modify your procedure to pass the shell test at that website, under "Coding Exercise: Poetic Analysis" section?

I will accept your answer nonetheless, for Python 3 shell.

Thanks a million.

Comment: Thanks a million koukouviou.
It works.
I just had to modify your procedure and give one indentation to    return    and it works.
You are brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, for those who are interested in the great answer by koukouviou earlier and that works in a Python 3 shell, here it is:

```
def words(P):
    poem_words = P.lower().split()
    poem_words.sort()

    # Remove the # signs
    poem_words = [x for x in poem_words if (x != '#' and x != '###')]

    # Initialize variables
    temp = ""
    max_count = 0
    icount = 1
    max_word = ""

    # Do the loop
    for i in range(len(poem_words)):
        if temp == poem_words[i]:
            icount += 1
        else:
            temp = poem_words[i]
            icount = 1
        if icount > max_count:
            max_count = icount
            max_word = temp
    return max_word


poem = "Here is a line like sparkling wine\nLine up fast or be the last\n# # #"
print(words(poem))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
attached a newer version as the input are keep coming through input

A = []
counter = []

while True:
    S = input().lower()
    if S == "###": 
        print(A[counter.index(max(counter))])
        break
    SS = S.split()
    for i in range(0,len(SS)):
        if SS[i] not in A:
            A.append(SS[i])
            counter.append(0)
        else:
            counter[A.index(SS[i])]+= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. My code includes the possibility if two or more words have the same number
of appearance.

```
    def reading():
        global ListLine                 # We make variable 'ListLine' global in case if function CountWord() does not take it
        ListLine = []                   # We define an empty list 'ListLine'
        while True:
            Line = input()              # A line of poem is entered
            NewLine = Line.split()      # We make a list 'NewLine' of individual words

            for i in range(0, len(NewLine)):
                NewString = NewLine[i].lower()    # For each word in list 'NewLine' we make it lowercase
                NewLine.insert(i, NewString)      # We add to a list a lowercase version of a individual word value at position i
                del NewLine[i + 1]                # We delete original word at position i + 1

            ListLine = ListLine + NewLine

            if ListLine[len(ListLine) - 1] == "###":  # If line ends with '###', the loop ends
                break
        return ListLine                           # We get a list of individual words


    def CountWord(ListLine):
        CountList = []                          # We define an empty list 'CountList'
        for i in range(0, len(ListLine)):
            CountWord = ListLine.count(ListLine[i])  # Counting how many times an individual word appears in 'ListLine'
            CountList.insert(i, CountWord)           # We add to a list the result of frequency of appearance of an individual word at position i

        return CountList       # We get a list of counts of individual words


    def Word(CountList):
        global WordList   # We make variable 'WordList' global in case if function RemoveDuplicate() does not take it
        WordList = []     # We defined an empty list 'WordList'
        for i in range(0, len(CountList)):
            if CountList[i] == max(CountList):  # For each index in 'CountList' that has a value of highest count of appearance of individual word,
                Word = ListLine[i]              # get a word from 'ListLine' which have the same index
                WordList.insert(i, Word)        # Add to a list a word at position i a.k.a index
            elif CountList[i] != max(ListLine):  # If above condition was not met, we skip a step
                continue

        return WordList     # We get a list of individual words that appears the most in 'NewLine', but might contains duplicates.


    def RemoveDuplicate(Wordlist):
        ResultList = []   # We define an empty list 'CountList'
        for i in WordList:
            if i not in ResultList:  # To remove duplicates we define a condtiotion; if a list 'ResulList' does not contain
                                     # an individual word we insert in a list.
                ResultList.append(i)

        String = ' '.join(ResultList)  # We convert a list into a string

        if String.endswith('###'):     # If string ends with '###', we remove last four characters (space included),
                                       # else return just final result
            return String[:-4]
        else:
            return String


    print(RemoveDuplicate(Word(CountWord(reading())))) # Print the output
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through the same tutorial and came up with the code sample below. It's not great code but keeps to the limits of the tutorial and is commented to explain each step. This **does** pass the tester on the source page.

```
#create 4 lists
newList=[]    #to intake each line of new text
fulList=[]    #combine all text in one long list
uniqueList=[] #list of unique words
wordFreq=[]   #frequency of those unique words

#take in all lines
while True:
   newLine=input()
   if newLine=="###":
      break
   newList=newLine.lower().split() #convert all words to lowercase
   fulList=fulList+newList         #add this to the fulList of all words

#clear memory of items we no longer need
newList=[]
newLine=[]

#find and store all unique words
for i in range(0,len(fulList)): #scan all of fulList
   checkWord = fulList[i]
   if checkWord in uniqueList:  #if we already have that word, skip it
      continue
   uniqueList.append(checkWord) #otherwise add it to the uniqueList

#create a blank freq table of same length as uniqueList
#technically this was created on line 5, but now you understand the context
#note the use of len(uniqueList) so both lists are the same length
wordFreq=[0]*(len(uniqueList))

#now iterate through each word in your uniqueList using range i
#checking for every word in the fullList which we will iterate using range j
for i in range(0,len(uniqueList)):
   for j in range(0,len(fulList)):
      if uniqueList[i]==fulList[j]:
         wordFreq[i] = wordFreq[i]+1 #increase the count for that item

#create a variable for most common word, this is the largest number in wordFreq
maxWord = max(wordFreq)

#iterate through wordFreq to find that value
for i in range(0,len(wordFreq)):
   if wordFreq[i]==maxWord:
      print(uniqueList[i]) #print that word from uniqueList
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is simplier than above.

```
poem=''
while True:
    poem=poem+' '+(input())  
    if poem.endswith('###'): break  

poem=poem.lower()  
listOFstring=poem.split()  

l=[]  
for i in listOFstring:  
    l.append(listOFstring.count(i))  

print(listOFstring[l.index(max(l))])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from statistics import mode

List = []
while True:
   line = input()
   if  line == '###':
      break
   else:
      List = List + line.lower().split()

print(mode(List))
```